# To get around HTML5 color input problems in IE and some Chrome vesions

Tags: css, html

Please, could anyone help me to solve the problem with this page http://gecko.sashaz.com/index.html. It is supposed to be a color selector, but the background image doesn't load in some browsers. Seems it has something to do with input color type method. How do I get around it in IE Edge, etc.?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- CLICK TO CHANGE COLOR -->
<input type="color" value="#e73d18">

<!-- Image Credit -->


</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://gecko.sashaz.com/green_Gecko.jpg)no-repeat; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    /* removes default styling from input color element */

    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    /* makes input (color swatch) 100% size of container */

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* mix blend mode makes the color of the swatch alter the image behind it. */

    mix-blend-mode: hue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* removes default styling from input color element */

::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}

::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}

::-moz-color-swatch,
::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
/* Image Credit */

a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: skyblue;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

background-image: instead of only background.

Comment: Thanks, changed to background-image. Didn't change IE Edge behaviour. Shows the number of the initial color and doesn't call the color palette selector.